# 404 Not Found error in large execution time file

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, internal-server-error, php-ini

Hope you doing well

I am facing with a problem and not getting the solution.
I have a folder which contains data of all weeks and years in structure "data/year/week/" and every folder contains a "weekly.xml" file starts from year 2003 to 2014. 
I need to get some XML data from all years and weeks folder's weekly.xml file. I am getting all correctly when I use to get 10 weeks data from all years but when I increase the size I Got an Internal server error with message "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request" 
I extended The execution time from INI but still getting problems.
When I call all 52 weeks from only a year all date's are coming correctly without any error.

Thanks for Help...

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I get this kind of error I get an HTTP 503 Internal Server Error. 404 means the file you're looking for was not found by your apache or other server.

Here's something that's worked for me in the past where I reset the PHP's timeout for each task. Just be careful with this sort of approach as you don't want this to spin off into an infinite loop.

```
$done = false;
while(!$done) {
  // Reset PHP's time limit so that you don't time out.
  set_time_limit(30);

  // Process single file here ...

  if (!$isLastFile) {
    $done = true;
  }
}
```

Ideally you're going to want to cache the results from previous years and months which I'm assuming won't change. However you need to run through all these files at least once to build up such a cache.

I might also suggest using a multi threaded approach using pcntl_fork if that available on your OS. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: I have set time limit to infinite but still same problem

Comment: Is your error reporting level set yo E_ALL? This might reveal another error that's holding this up. Alternatively include a section of code where you're having this issue.